# How do I run a bash command in a script while the rest of the script does not have to wait for that single bash command finish its execution

Tags: bash, multithreading, shell

I am running a loop in my script and there is an individual command in that script that takes a long time to run. When the loop runs, it takes a very long time to finish because of that individual command. This long command requires all the other code to be executed. For that reason, I would like the script to continue running and not wait for that individual long command to finish its execution.

Websites all over the internet say to use the & sign at the end of the long command to run a separate thread. The issue is that when I use this command it ignores the lines before it which set up the command to be usable. That command does not need to be completed for the rest of the script to work.The link shows 2 images. The first shows the desired outcome and the second shows the poor outcome when using the & sign at the end of the long command.

[First Image is the desired setup and the second is the setup when using the & sign at the end of the long command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yG0X.png)

Here is a similar example of code I am working with:

```
for ((i = 1 ; i <= $howeverManyUserWants ; i++)); do

rm '/path/to/temporaryFile.js'

sed s/codeToChange/randomNum <path/to/template > path/to/temporaryFile.js

node temporaryFile.js #this takes command takes a long time to run

rm  path/to/temporaryFile.js

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On surface, the question asks multiple iteration of a long-running jobs in parallel, to save execution time. The job itself seems to be a simulation, which uses a different random number of each iteration (s ... randomNum ). From the OP, it's not possible to know what are the resources for that job.

One issue with the current code is that it uses the same temporary file repeatedly. This can create timing issue - if the node engine will not be able to read the temporary file before the rm will execute.

Possible solution:

```
for ((i = 1 ; i <= $howeverManyUserWants ; i++)); do
{
    sed s/codeToChange/randomNum <path/to/template > path/to/temporaryFile-$i.js
    node temporaryFile$i.js #this takes command takes a long time to run
    rm -f path/to/tempporaryFile$i.js
} &
sleep 1
done
```

The sleep is suggested to avoid the the "thunder" effect, where all instances of node will start at the same time. The code above assumes that the node scripts can work in parallel, and do not use temporary files that will overwrite each other, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have multithreaded the loop itself. thanks for the sleep to stop the thunder effect too.

Comment: @JustinGeisen You welcome. Wanted also to suggest that if you have large number jobs which may overwhelm the system, then consider capping the number of concurrent jobs using `xargs` or `parallel` or similar.

Answer (score -1):

The question is, since I do not understand what you want exactly achieve, when you want to synchronize threads, at which point in the program. Waiting for a job to complete can be done using *jobs* command. With *jobs* command you can also let the system run as many jobs as you desire at once.

I provide you here complete solution, which allows setting the number of threads you have on your machine. Thus the "thunder" effect will not occur, since only as many jobs will run at once as you have threads in your system:

```
#! /bin/bash

NUM_THREADS=4

for ((i = 1 ; i <= $howeverManyUserWants ; i++)); do
    while true
    do
        CNT=$(jobs -p | wc -l)
        if [[ $CNT -lt $NUM_THREADS ]]; then

                echo "($i from $howeverManyUserWants)"
                {
                        sed s/codeToChange/randomNum < path/to/template > path/to/temporaryFile$i.js
                        node temporaryFile$i.js
                        rm -f path/to/temporaryFile$i.js
                } &
                break
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: why you downvote the answer, I provide you best possible solution to the problem, the solution above by dash-o will not work if you have a large number of files to process, it can exhauste resources, more over it introduce performance penalty by sleep 1

Comment: I can not comment on why you were downvoted. As for you comments about the solution that I've posted: the sleep was done to mitigate to "thunder" effect, since the OP ask for all jobs to be started at the same time. Usually 'node' jobs will take source resources to starts, but are usually very light on resources, as they post calls to other services.